# SQL find references with single occurrences

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, aggregate

I am trying to find a pure SQL solution for the following problem:

If I sell paint and paintbrushes, and keep a record of which colors are sold like this:

```
    select OrderNumber, Product, Product_Type, Qty from Sales

+-------------+------------+--------------+-----+
| OrderNumber |  Product   | Product_Type | Qty |
+-------------+------------+--------------+-----+
|        0001 | Red        | Paint        |   1 |
|        0001 | Blue       | Paint        |   2 |
|        0001 | Green      | Paint        |   1 |
|        0001 | Paintbrush | Brush        |   1 |
|        0002 | Green      | Paint        |   1 |
|        0002 | Paintbrush | Brush        |   1 |
|        0003 | Blue       | Paint        |   4 |
|        0003 | Red        | Paint        |   5 |
|        0003 | Paintbrush | Brush        |   1 |
|        0004 | Blue       | Paint        |   2 |
|        0004 | Paintbrush | Brush        |   1 |
|        0005 | Green      | Paint        |   1 |
|        0005 | Paintbrush | Brush        |   1 |
+-------------+------------+--------------+-----+
```

Is there a way to isolate orders where only one tin of paint was sold, and that tin of paint was green? I want to ignore paintbrushes because every order includes a paintbrush. So from the example dataset, the desired results would be orders #0002 and #0005 because on each of those orders the total qty of paint tins sold was 1, and those tins were green.

I think the answer lies possibly with a group by clause and some aggregate functions and possibly a sub query. However, i'm not exactly sure how to combine these to get the results i need.

Comment: @Siyual This would return a record from order #0001 which is not the required result because tins of red and blue paint were also sold on that order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, filter out all brushes. This can be done in the `where` clause.

Then you need to process each order as a bunch of records. This can be achieved with `group by OrderNumber, Product_Type` which breaks your table into order groups. Then you can filter these groups in the `having` clause to find only those with a single sold item in them.

```
select OrderNumber
  from Sales
  where Product_Type <> 'Brush'
  group by OrderNumber, Product_Type
  having sum(qty) = 1
     and min(Product) = 'Green'
```

Comment: Add little explanation to your code. You will have a +1 from me.

Comment: What does `min(Product)` do here?

Comment: @Dmitry Egorov, Thank You!

Comment: @JenR: we only need `'Green'` `Product`s. `min` (or some other aggregate function not affecting the semantics) is required in having because the Product is not listed in the `group by`. `min` does not affect semantics in this case since only one record is ensured by `sum(qty) = 1`